# Can I use a variable to call a method?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

Can I call a method when the method name is stored in a variable? What's the syntax? Suppose I have the following PHP code:

```
class MyClass {
    public $default;

    function index() {
        /* call method named by $this->default */
    }
    function method_1() {}
    function method_2() {}
    ...
}
```

`index()` is called by default when the class is initialised if no other method is specifically called.

How can I call one of the methods from within `index()` using the `MyClass->$default` property? That is, if I would ordinarily write:

```
function index() { $this->method_1(); }
```

can I use my default variable to call the correct method?

Comment: Take a look of http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can i use a variable to call a method?

Yes you can. For example, inside an object:

```
$method = "method_1";

if (method_exists($this, $method))
 $this->{$method}();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can using this syntax:

```
$methodname = 'method_1';
$this->$methodname();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) workaround:

```
call_user_func( array($this,$methodname), $arg...);
```