# Access PHP function of a class

Tags: php

How to access the PHP function of a class where the function is stored in variable?

For example:

```
$functionname = "say_hello";
$obj = new Class();
$obj -> $functionname();
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. http://codepad.viper-7.com/ttfLas

Comment: Dup of [Can i use a variable to call a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276231/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if function name is stored in a variable check if it is exists and is callable like

```
   if ( method_exists( $product, $method ) ) {
print $product->$method(); // invoke the method
}
```

then check if it is callable

```
if ( is_callable( array( $product, $method) ) ) {
print $product->$method(); // invoke the method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :) 

my flow of program goes in if clauses but still I dont get the returned value  (Here i.e.  print $product->$method() 
but still I dont get the value of function )

Answer (score 1):

Use a [callback](http://it.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback)

Quick sample: `array($obj, $functionname)`

```
call_user_func(array($obj, $functionname), your parameters);
```

A complete explanation on the reference link above

Comment: Thanks for reply :)
but still I dont get the value of function (here i.e. value of $functionname).

Comment: If Your function returns something then you can obtain it as `$result = call_user_func(array($obj, $functionname));`

Answer (score 0):

```
private function __get($name) {
$method = 'get'.$name;
return $this->$method();
}
```

write the __get function which builds the method name and calls it