# Last two lines of code in one statement in PHP

Tags: php

In order to optimize my code, how can I write the last two lines of code in one statement?

```
$v1 = functionName;
$strR = "get".$v1;
echo $obj->$strR();
```

As I want to get `$obj->getfunctionName()`.

Comment: he just tries to save a few lines

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a variable to call a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276231/can-i-use-a-variable-to-call-a-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enclose it in `{}` to shorten your code, but this will not make a significant difference (if any at all) in terms of execution speed:

```
echo $obj->{"get" . $v1}();
```

This functionality is described in user-contributed comments on the [PHP5 OOP introductory page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), though I do not consider that official documentation.

Comment: For the morbidly curious: Some quick and dirty benchmarking with 10M  executions (avg of 10 executions of 1M each) shows this runs about 2% faster than the code in the question.

Comment: @ctrahey So for Yahoo! or Facebook, this makes a measureable difference. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael: Please provide some reference to the PHP manual where that is documented.

Comment: @hakre I've already been looking for _official_ mentions of this in the docs and will add when _if_ find them. There are user-contrib comments on it, no official docs I've uncovered so far.

Comment: let's keep it classy, @hakre My comment, while true, came with a hint of tongue-in-cheek; if you really need 2%, more power to you. Most programs, however, can be optimized with orders of magnitude more impact by rethinking how they work. The performance gain makes sense to me since PHP needn't involve the symbol table. And why do you need me to give you proof? Just run it yourself 10M times like I did.

Comment: Also, I suspect a good place to start in the docs is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with no optimization:

```
<?
Echo "\$obj->getfunctionName();";
?>
```